# What is causing my autowired object to throw a Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, javabeans, autowired

I have a public final class that extends `Configured` and implements `Tool` that refuses to see an autowired variable. This class is passed to the static `ToolRunner.run` method and I'm not sure what impact I should expect from this added layer of complexity.

I've offloaded the logic of the `context.getBean` to a separate class and the autowiring works but introduces more bugs (nulls the configuration of the ToolRunner).  The code for this separate class is a carbon copy of the code in the `Driver` class and is annotated as `@Component`. Why the `Autowired` works for a separate class but not this one is unknown to me.

Here's the code from the Driver class:

```
@Component
public final class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {
private static Driver driver = new Driver();
@Autowired
private Connection connection;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),driver, args);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception{
AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HdfsConfig.class);
driver = context.getBean(Driver.class);
\\and it continues till I hit my getConnection NPE
```

Here's HdfsConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"shared.folder"}
public class HdfsConfig{

@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
\\So on and so on until I return my configuration
```

What I really want to do is retain my ToolRunner info and connection object in the class with everything populated and happy. I suspect something regarding the nature of my `Driver` variable is breaking things but the reason is escape my feeble brain.

Comment: Here is a generic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: It is also (probably) a bad idea to autowire the `connection` variable.  Shouldn't you be managing connections via a connection pool?  Or by using Spring JDBCtemplate? https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/